# Oracle SQL , how to use current date - a specified date

Tags: sql, oracle

For getting current date i use this..

```
select extract(year from sysdate) from dual;
```

For getting the date that my database hold i use this..

```
select extract(year from startdate) from staff;
```

But now i am trying to update a field call serviceYears inside staff, by using

`current year - year of start date`

to get the amount of years the staff have committed to work. how do i achieve it..

i am using oracle sql

**Thanks!**

I tried to use

```
SQL> select dual.sysdate-staff.startdatefrom dual,staff;

select dual.sysdate-staff.startdatefrom from dual,staff
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

I also tried

```
select SYSDATE-to_date('01-jan-2007','dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;

But it return me
SYSDATE-TO_DATE('01-JAN-2007','DD-MON-YYYY')
--------------------------------------------
                                  2136.93719
```

How do i just get the year?

Comment: should "serviceYears" be an integer? ie if a staff member has worked 6 years 1 month what do you want and what about 6 years 11 months? also this would be magnitudes better as a view/virtual column as the data is going to need maintaining all the time otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this

```
UPDATE STAFF
SET serviceYear = ROUND((sysdate - startDate)/365)
```

Ex:

```
select ROUND((sysdate - to_date('01-JAN-2007','DD-MON-YYYY'))/365) 
from dual; -- returns 6


select ROUND((sysdate - to_date('01-JAN-2005','DD-MON-YYYY'))/365,2) 
from dual; -- returns 7.85
```

Updated:

```
SELECT 
FLOOR((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-JAN-2005','DD-MON-YYYY'))/365) YEARDOWN,
CEIL((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-JAN-2005','DD-MON-YYYY'))/365) YearUP
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: How do i round down instead , cause some of the worker i see start work from Year 2005, but it count service year as 8, whileas now is only year 2012. such as this startDate 01-JAN-05, but length of service is 8

Comment: Not keen on seeing the number of years worked out based on the number of days -- months_between() would be a better option, I think.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need dual.sysdate - you can just reference sysdate.

```
select sysdate-staff.startdatefrom from staff
```

Comment: How do i get the answer in year :)

Comment: this will be in days - so you would divide by 365 to get the (fractional) year. then you could round.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better served by a combination of `FLOOR` and `MONTHS_BETWEEN`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (start_date DATE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (TO_DATE('20070930','YYYYMMDD'));

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), start_date)/12) yrs_between_start_dt_and_today FROM t
  2  ;

YRS_BETWEEN_START_DT_AND_TODAY
------------------------------
                             5

SQL>
```

You can adjust your rounding as needed.  Moreover, this solution plays better with leap years and such, as compared to dividing by a hard-coded 365.

Comment: Yep, +1 for the month-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can measure it in months, try the months_between function:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/months_between.php

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions094.htm#i78039

Could take that and divide by 12 to get the year.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT extract(year from sysdate)-extract(year from TDATE) 
      FROM R_M 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=1
```